# Having trouble trying to grab a specific key value from Stripe API using dot notation with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, stripe-payments

I'm pulling data from the Stripe API from a test invoice. I'm trying to narrow down to pull a specific key value pair using dot notation, but I'm having trouble pulling the data from a specific key value as it seems nester deeper than the rest of the data (not sure if that's the right terminology).

The data I'm trying to pull the data from is from `period: end:` and from `period: start:` roughly from lines 44-46.

If I use dot notation in my code it works when the key value pair is on the same line, such as `sheet.getRange(3,2).setValue([content.amount_due]);`. But it seems as if "period: end" and "period: start" are nested deeper.

I tried doing something like `[content.lines.data.period.end]` but it didn't work. It returns this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property "end" from undefined.`

Here's the full data pulled from the API (note: `"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` represents data that's been hidden):

````
  ""id"": ""in_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
  ""object"": ""invoice"",
  ""amount_due"": 800,
  ""amount_paid"": 800,
  ""amount_remaining"": 0,
  ""application_fee"": null,
  ""attempt_count"": 1,
  ""attempted"": true,
  ""auto_advance"": false,
  ""billing"": ""charge_automatically"",
  ""billing_reason"": ""subscription_cycle"",
  ""charge"": ""ch_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
  ""closed"": true,
  ""created"": 1552077120,
  ""currency"": ""usd"",
  ""custom_fields"": null,
  ""customer"": ""cus_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
  ""date"": 1552077120,
  ""default_payment_method"": null,
  ""default_source"": null,
  ""description"": null,
  ""discount"": null,
  ""due_date"": null,
  ""ending_balance"": 0,
  ""finalized_at"": 1552080770,
  ""footer"": null,
  ""forgiven"": false,
  ""hosted_invoice_url"": ""https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/invst_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
  ""invoice_pdf"": ""https://pay.stripe.com/invoice/invst_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pdf"",
  ""lines"": {
    ""object"": ""list"",
    ""data"": [
      {
        ""id"": ""sub_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
        ""object"": ""line_item"",
        ""amount"": 800,
        ""currency"": ""usd"",
        ""description"": null,
        ""discountable"": true,
        ""livemode"": false,
        ""metadata"": {
        },
        ""period"": {
          ""end"": 1554755515,
          ""start"": 1552077115
        },
        ""plan"": {
          ""id"": ""xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
          ""object"": ""plan"",
          ""active"": true,
          ""aggregate_usage"": null,
          ""amount"": 400,
          ""billing_scheme"": ""per_unit"",
          ""created"": 1407529859,
          ""currency"": ""usd"",
          ""interval"": ""month"",
          ""interval_count"": 1,
          ""livemode"": false,
          ""metadata"": {
          },
          ""name"": ""sdf"",
          ""nickname"": null,
          ""product"": ""prod_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
          ""statement_description"": null,
          ""statement_descriptor"": null,
          ""tiers"": null,
          ""tiers_mode"": null,
          ""transform_usage"": null,
          ""trial_period_days"": null,
          ""usage_type"": ""licensed""
        },
        ""proration"": false,
        ""quantity"": 2,
        ""subscription"": null,
        ""subscription_item"": ""si_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
        ""type"": ""subscription"",
        ""unique_line_item_id"": ""sli_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx""
      }
    ],
    ""has_more"": false,
    ""total_count"": 1,
    ""url"": ""/v1/invoices/in_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/lines""
  },
  ""livemode"": false,
  ""metadata"": {
  },
  ""next_payment_attempt"": null,
  ""number"": ""77E3C02-0025"",
  ""paid"": true,
  ""payment"": ""ch_1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
  ""payment_intent"": ""pi_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
  ""period_end"": 1552077115,
  ""period_start"": 1549657915,
  ""receipt_number"": ""2258-2679"",
  ""starting_balance"": 0,
  ""statement_description"": null,
  ""statement_descriptor"": null,
  ""status"": ""paid"",
  ""status_transitions"": {
    ""finalized_at"": 1552080770,
    ""marked_uncollectible_at"": null,
    ""paid_at"": 1552080772,
    ""voided_at"": null
  },
  ""subscription"": ""sub_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"",
  ""subtotal"": 800,
  ""tax"": null,
  ""tax_percent"": null,
  ""total"": 800,
  ""webhooks_delivered_at"": 1552077123
}"```


  [1]: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/retrieve
````

Comment: [Stripe API reference page](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/retrieve) just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is an array, try `content.lines.data[0].period.end`.